# Is there a way to passthru SMTP sendings to another server?

Tags: php, email, smtp, port, forward

we currently got a problem with our company smtp-server and our admin is currently not available. So I wanted to try to send the mails from another server. On our main server there is no connection possible due to a blacklist entry on our own system. So is there a way that I have in my script a server B that listens to this request and send this to the real smtp-server?

So that I can set my connection settings on Server A in PHPMailer to Server B and the B-Server then forwards/passes through the request to the SMTP-Server?

Does anyone knows help?

The problem ist not on Server A. A ping and telnet to all SMTP-Ports of other servers is possible. But a ping or telnet from Server B is possible.

I am thankful for any idea.

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: Yes, it is, but it goes away from programming so it is not really on topic here. And I wouldn't recommend administering a mail server yourself unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I thought there would maybe a way of like port forwarding to another server all requests on 587 or else? Maybe someone did that sometimes and knows?

Comment: That is also possible, but still risky unless you can properly limit it to only accept connections from that single server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just port-forwarded the requests from one to another server with iptables.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1xx.xx.xx.xx -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 2xx.xx.xx.xx:587
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Just replaced the placeholders with my two IP addresses and use the new server as relay for sending mails with smtp.

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this essential hint with the `-j MASQUERADE` option above.

As I needed the forwarding permanently I want to provide a `cloud-init.txt` here for further reference:

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
packages:
   - iptables-persistent
write_files:
  - path: /etc/sysctl.conf
    content: | 
      # added by cloud init
      net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  
    append: true
runcmd:
- sysctl -p
- iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.1:25
- iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 567 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.1:567
- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
- service netfilter-persistent save
```